# How to access the prototype function in jquery

Tags: jquery, prototype

Please refer below prototype.

```
var sfSvgRender = function (element) {
    this.svgLink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";


};
sfSvgRender.prototype = (function () {
    this.drawPath = function (options, element) {

        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
        $(path).attr(options);
        $(path).appendTo(element);

    }
})();
```

when am creating the object like this

```
var svgRenderObj= new sfSvgRender();
```

svgRenderObj only contains "svgLink" property . i cant able to access the "drawpath" function.
how can i access the prototype function in jquery ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Why don't you do something like this : `var sfSvgRender = function (element) {
    this.svgLink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    sfSvgRender.prototype.drawPath = function (options, element) {
 // your code   
    };
};` , Then call it as `svgRenderObj.drawPath(x,y);`

Comment: if am using prototype function inside the sfSvgRender means. it will reintialize/create every time instance created. thats not perfect solution

Comment: Sorry , I didn't know your requirement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the prototype to an object, so you have to create one. Use `new`

```
sfSvgRender.prototype = new (function () {
    this.drawPath = function (options, element) {    
        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
        $(path).attr(options);
        $(path).appendTo(element);    
    }
})();
```

You can also use an object literal

```
sfSvgRender.prototype ={
    drawPath: function (options, element) {

        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
        $(path).attr(options);
        $(path).appendTo(element);

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Musa. Can you please refer my solution and tell me what is the difference between your solution and me. your solution also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one more solution.Please refer below code snippet.

```
sfSvgRender.prototype ={
    drawPath: function (options, element) {

        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
        $(path).attr(options);
        $(path).appendTo(element);

    }
};
```

Thanks,

Siva